# How to change one of the state object value correctly with useState React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

I'm trying to change my state with useState hook from.
My hook looks like.

`const [data, setData] = useState(initialDataState);`

Initial state:

```
const initialDataState = {
  EMAIL_TYPE: "",
  NAME_TYPE: "",
  GENDER_TYPE: "",
  ZIP_TYPE: "",
  DEVICES_TYPE: []
};
```

I call `setData` from the function with 2 props type of state to change and value.
My function:

```
const handleChange = (key, value) => {
    setData(prevState => {
      return { ...prevState, ...(prevState[key] = value) };
    });
  };
```

AS RESULT when I call my `handleChange` function I can't change correctly value, because can't get correct key in prevState.

My question is: "How correctly change state in cases when you are getting key in which you want to change the value without state mutating"

Comment: change ```return { ...prevState, ...(prevState[key] = value) };``` to ```return { ...prevState, prevState[key]: value };```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the existing state and the key you want to update

```
const handleChange = (key, value) => {
  setData(prevState => {
    return {
      ...prevState,
      [key]: value
    };
  });
};
```